# Kotlin: Find most common element in collection

Tags: hashmap, kotlin

I am writing a function that iterates through a collection and finds the most common items occurring in it.

Here is what I have so far to get the values and add the number of times they appear in the collection. I'm putting the value into a map as a key and the number of times it appears as its value.

```
fun mostCommon(input: Collection<Int>): Set<Int> {
    var newMap: MutableMap<Int, Int> = HashMap()
    for (item in input) {
        if (newMap.containsKey(item)) {
            //TODO: add 1 to value if key is found
        } else {
            newMap.put(item, 1)
        }
    }
    return emptySet()
}
```

I am having trouble finding a way to add 1 to its value if the key already exists.

I tried doing this:

```
newMap[item] +=1
```

But I get an error about plusAssign(1) not being allowed on Nullable receiver.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you already noticed, the error was related to nullability-handling. I'd suggest a more functional approach without explicit looping but simple grouping:

```
val numbersByElement = input.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
//gives something like this {1=3, 2=5, 3=4, 5=2, 4=1}
```

The result is a Map with the elements from `input` as its keys and the number of occurrences of the elements as the corresponding values.

You can now find the most common element with `maxBy`:

```
numbersByElement.maxBy { it.value }?.key // gives an Int?
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of groupingBy. New of groupBy, but this will solve different problems. Nice!

Comment: Wow, this is slick. I had quick follow up question about the `{ it }`. What exactly is that doing, does it stand for the elements in the input?

Comment: Exactly, it is the current element from input itself, you normally use it to map to some element's attribute e.g. but in your case it's simply the integer directly :)

Comment: How about if I have two inputs with the same quantity? e.g: {2=5,3=5}
What's maxBy{it.value}?.key will return? How to return the min key or the max key in that case?

Answer (score 7):

`Map.get` returns an `Int?`, i.e. if no item is found, `null` will be returned. You can utilize the elvis operator to deal with that:

```
val newMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

for (item in input) {
    newMap[item] = (newMap[item] ?: 0) + 1
}
```

Another alternative is to use Java 8's [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
newMap.merge(item, 1) { i, j -> i + j }
// or the equivalent
newMap.merge(item, 1, Int::plus)
```

This will put `1` in the map, if the key is not present yet, and otherwise apply the lambda to the old and new value, in our case add the old value to the new value and store the result under the key.

Comment: great solution although it's Java :-)

Answer (score 2):

elegant nullsafe solution with Kotlin-1.4 preview

```
@Test
fun testFindOutMostCommonStringInList() {
    val mostCommon = findMostCommonInList(listOf("Foo", "Boo", null, "Foo", "Hello"))
    assertEquals("Foo", mostCommon)
}

@Test
fun testFindOutMostCommonIntInList() {
    val mostCommon = findMostCommonInList(listOf(1, 2, null, 3, 4, 5, 1))
    assertEquals(1, mostCommon)
}

private fun <T>findMostCommonInList(list : List<T>) : T? {
    return list
        .groupBy { it }
        .maxByOrNull { it.value.size }
        ?.key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work.

```
val arr = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,2,3,1,4,5,2,7,8,2,3,3,3,3)
val maxOccurring = arr.groupBy { it }.mapValues { it.value.size }.maxBy { it.value }?.key
```

Returns 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering @groff07 questions
[@groff07 questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAkuo.png)

if u have two inputs with the same quantity, don't use :

```
numbersByElement.maxBy { it.value }?.key
```

beacause it will give the first key that
gain max quantity

instead, u can use your own filtering, example i want tp print 2 which is the min e.g: {2=5,3=5}

```
val maxValue = numbersByElement.values.max()
var minkey = 5 //if it is guaranteed that max key is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
for (map in numbersByElement) {
    if (map.value == maxValue) {
        if (map.key < minkey) {
            minkey = map.key
        }
    }
}
```

pirntln(minKey)

more explanation: [techiedelight](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-maximum-value-key-in-a-kotlin-map/)